# Category page with posts from 2 different childcategories

Tags: theme-development

I have a category and will query posts from 2 different child categories 
see below.

This is my structure

```
1 category
  - 1.1 category <- her we are (on this category i will show the posts from 1.1.1 and 1.1.2)
    -- 1.1.1 category <- In this category are the posts
    -- 1.1.2 category <- And this category are the posts

2 category
  - 2.1 category
    -- 2.1.1 category
    -- 2.1.2 category
```

Thx for help.

Comment: Which categories you want to get posts from? Please explain your question better by [editing it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/167495/edit).

Comment: I edit the question. I will get posts from 1.1.1 & 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include posts from one or more specific categories, you can use and define [category__in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameter in your WordPress query. Like this, here is an example.

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => array( 11, 15 ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Where `11, 15` are the category ids of the categories that you want to include posts from. You can add as many categories as you want. You just have to add comma separated ids of those categories.

Comment: Ok i will try this. Thx for now.

Comment: Thx it works perfectly, many many thx i wasted many hour for this yesterday.

Comment: You did not waste your time. That's how we learn. First you try and search for a solution and if you are not still not able to get it right, ask here. :)